# Is there TeX/LaTeX command that outputs no text?

Tags: typography

I'm looking for something like `\nothing`, which will output no text. I need to put it between an apostrophe and closing quotes:

```
He said: ``I found `peace.'''
```

I have to do something like:

```
He said: ``I found `peace.'\nothing{}''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained on the [Texbook](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf) chapter 2, exercise 2.3:

> In case you need to type quotes within quotes, for example a single
>   quote followed by a double quote, you can’t simply type ’’’ because
>   TEX will interpret this as ”’ (namely, double quote followed by single
>   quote). If you have already read Chapter 5, you might expect that the
>   solution will be to use grouping—namely, to type something like {’}’’.
>   But it turns out that this doesn’t produce the desired result, because
>   there is usually less space following a single right quote than there
>   is following a double right quote: What you get is ’”, which is indeed
>   a single quote followed by a double quote (if you look at it closely
>   enough), but it looks almost like three equally spaced single quotes.
>   On the other hand, you certainly won’t want to type ’␣’’, because that
>   space is much too large—it’s just as large as the space between
>   words—and TEX might even start a new line at such a space when making
>   up a paragraph! The solution is to type ’\thinspace’’, which produces
>   ’ ” as desired.

### TL;DR

To have a satisfying look of nested quotes with the right spacing, use `'\thinspace''`

But if you really want them close, `\relax` also works, or placing them in groups `{'}''`

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach for this specific case: Use the `csquotes` package which supports nesting and correct spacing. Then use

```
He said: \enquote{I found \enquote{peace.}}
```